# MS Exchange does not deliver E-mails after disabling DNS Recursion

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010

I have the following problem. I have setup an MS Exchange 2010 server. Mail delivery works fine. But as soon as I disable recursion on my MS DNS server (same host) all the Mails stuck in a DnsConnector Queue on my exchange server.

Does someone know how I can configure exchange or the DNS server in order to have recursion disabled and my mails will still go outbound?

Comment: 1) why do you want to disable recursion? 2) how do you expect your server to be able to look up other domain's DNS records if recursion is disabled?

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're asking and the answer is that the Windows DNS client is a stub resolver and cannot follow DNS referrals. When you disable recursion on your DNS server you break the DNS client on the Exchange server because the DNS client on the Exchange server isn't capable of following referrals from the DNS server.

Assuming that the DNS server has an empty cache, the DNS server will refer the DNS client to the root hint servers that are loaded into the DNS server cache from the cache.dns zone file on the server.

Assuming that the DNS server performed recursion for the domain in question before recursion was disabled, and assuming that that information is still in the DNS server cache, and assuming that you then disable recursion on the server, the DNS server will refer the DNS client to those name servers as returned with the prior recursive lookup for the domain in question but the DNS client is unable to follow this referral.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to disable it? DNS recursion is enabled by default, and as long as it's an internal DNS server I don't see why you would want to change that?.

However, you can specify that the Send Connector is to use a different set of DNS servers than the default for the server. This would enable your send connector to do mx lookups against external instead of internal DNS servers. Details to be found here:

[Configure Hub Transport Server Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123514.aspx)

Comment: My hosting company send me an email to disable recursion as this allows other people to attack other servers via my server. So should I setup this in the Send connector ?

Comment: So firewall off DNS so that others can't use it.

Comment: That is true for external accessible DNS servers. Internal DNS servers (which I'm hoping is not accessible from outside your LAN) are in theory less vulnerable to this. Your hosting company shouldnt care what's going on inside your LAN. But yes, you can mitigate this by using an external DNS on your send connector.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that other people cannot resolve our domain ? It is one server for web/email/dns, so there are websites running on the machine as well as the exchange for inbound and outbound...

Comment: Are you saying youre running public DNS, DC, Exchange and public Web Sites on the same server? asking for trouble, IMHO.

Comment: Yes correct. I know this is not the case it should be but DC was just needed to get started with Exchange. So hopefully we can do something there to get a "good" solution.

Comment: In that case you need to provide a better description of your current environment: network, firewalls, so forth. If I were you I'd get a consultant's help to get it right. You're on a fast track to failure with your current design.

Comment: I do not have information about networking, because it is a dedicated server rent at a hosting company. We just installed W2k8 and setup AD,DNS,IIS and Exchange. Now it seems we are forced to disable recursion in DNS which will break the Exchange server.

Comment: use a hosted DNS service instead of hosting it on your server. Do NOT publicly expose an AD-integrated DNS server on the internet.

Comment: Any recommendation for hosted dns servers ?

Comment: You have been forced into this position due to nothing other than you not understanding the technologies involved, and not understanding how best to architect your system. Those are big topics, though. Right now, I'd recommend you hire someone to help get this cleaned up and configured in a reliable, easily manageable way.

Comment: I totally agree with you but I am not the person who can make that decision and as I am forced into the issue that I won't get the budget for that at the moment I am trying to make the best out of the current solution.